What is the term for a clause that comes after a noun and describes a larger group of nouns that includes it?

I like apples, and sweet fruits in general.


He's good at hurdles, and really all agility sports.

What are these clauses called, where they imply the prior verb applies to a larger set of nouns than the one called out specifically first?

Yes, they're idiomatic, though illogical. *'I like dogs and animals.' One might prefer 'I like apples ... in fact, fruits in general.' A semi-corrective broadening.  I doubt such specific coordinate structures have a name.

It's an example of a generalization, but I guess you want a more specific term (that doesn't exist).

I'm open to an answer that isn't specifically about this case. What's a less specific name for it? Even getting closer like "clause" would be helpful.
